# CORS não está habilitando

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, aplicação-web, cors

Desenvolvi uma `API REST` em `Node.js` e preciso utilizá-la em meu front-end.

Já instalei a biblioteca [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) e habilitei em meu servidor mas continua dando o erro de acesso ao efetuar a requisição com `AJAX`.

**Habilitando CORS no Node.js**

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

**Chamando pela API no JQuery**

```
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  url: `localhost:3030/api/admin/employees`,
  data:fd,
  cache:false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success:function(data){
    console.log("success");
    console.log(data);
  },
});
```

**Erro no console do Chrome**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3030/api/admin/employees?_=1573153461164' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https

Comment: Tenta trocar a url por `http://localhost:3030/api/admin/employees`

Comment: Boa, agora está funcionando =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você não estava colocando a url completa e ele não identificava o protocolo da solicitação pro servidor. Mudar a url da requisição ajax para `http://localhost:3030/api/admin/employees` deve resolver o seu problema, pois passará a utilizar um protocolo válido, no caso HTTP.